# Matlab: how do I run the optimization (fmincon) repeately?

Tags: optimization, matlab

I am trying to follow the tutorial of using the optimization tool box in MATLAB. Specifically, I have a function

```
f = exp(x(1))*(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+4*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2)+1)+b
```

subject to the constraint:

```
(x(1))^2+x(2)-1=0,
-x(1)*x(2)-10<=0.
```

**and I want to minimize this function for a range of `b=[0,20]`.  (That is, I want to minimize this function for `b=0`, `b=1`,`b=2` ... and so on).**

Below is the steps taken from the MATLAB's tutorial webpage(http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-equality-and-inequality-constraints.html), how should I change the code so that, the optimization will run for 20 times, and save the optimal values for each b?

Step 1: Write a file `objfun.m`.

```
function f = objfun(x)
f = exp(x(1))*(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+4*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2)+1)+b;
```

Step 2: Write a file `confuneq.m` for the nonlinear constraints.

```
function [c, ceq] = confuneq(x)
% Nonlinear inequality constraints
c = -x(1)*x(2) - 10;
% Nonlinear equality constraints
ceq = x(1)^2 + x(2) - 1;
```

Step 3: Invoke constrained optimization routine.

```
x0 = [-1,1];            % Make a starting guess at the solution
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp');
[x,fval] = fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],... 
   @confuneq,options);
```

After 21 function evaluations, the solution produced is

```
x, fval
x =
   -0.7529    0.4332
fval =
    1.5093
```

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

**Update:
I tried your answer, but I am encountering problem with your step 2. Bascially, I just fill the my step 2 to your step 2 (below the comment "optimization just like before").**

```
 %initialize list of targets
b = 0:1:20;
%preallocate/initialize result vectors using zeros (increases speed)
opt_x = zeros(length(b));
opt_fval = zeros(length(b));
>> for idx = 1, length(b)
  objfun = @(x)objfun_builder(x,b)

  %optimization just like before
                x0 = [-1,1];            % Make a starting guess at the solution
                options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp');
                [x,fval] = fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],... 
                @confuneq,options);
  %end the stuff I fill in
  opt_x(idx) = x
  opt_fval(idx) = fval
end
```

However, it gave me the output is:

```
Error: "objfun" was previously used as a variable, conflicting
with its use here as the name of a function or command.
See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB
documentation for details.
```

Comment: @pyStarter, yes, I am trying to use a loop. But where should I declare the loop? I tried it in step1, but it doesn't work

Comment: Use a loop, cf. the example in my answer.

Comment: @updated question: Is the original m-file still in your path? This may be causing the problems. Another cause may be something being wrong with your syntax of the anonymous function. Alternatively, you may construct/pass the anonymous function directly as argument of fmincon to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: I think I remove the original objfun.m file (I didn't remove the constraint file).

Comment: This page is worth mentioning: [MATLAB Documentation: Passing Extra Parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html)

Comment: in your update you are taking the function handle of a function handle. objfun is already a function handle, from the syntax @(X) (some expression with X...) . When you call fmincon you use @objfun, which is actually eqivalent to @@(X)(some expression with x..). This is not valid

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to change about your code:

1. Creation of the objective function.
2. Multiple optimizations using a loop.

**1st Step**

For more flexibility with regard to `b`, you need to set up another function that returns a handle to the desired objective function, e.g.

```
function h = objfun_builder(x, b)
  h = @(x)(objfun(x));

  function f = objfun(x)
    f = exp(x(1))*(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+4*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2)+1) + b;
  end
end
```

A more elegant and shorter approach are [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), e.g.

```
objfun_builder = @(x,b)(exp(x(1))*(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+4*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2)+1) + b);
```

After all, this works out to be the same as above. It might be less intuitive for a Matlab-beginner, though.

**2nd Step**

Instead of placing an .m-file `objfun.m` in your path, you will need to call

```
objfun = @(x)(objfun_builder(x,myB));
```

to create an objective function in your workspace. In order to loop over the interval b=[0,20], use the following loop

```
%initialize list of targets
b = 0:1:20;
%preallocate/initialize result vectors using zeros (increases speed)
opt_x = zeros(length(b))
opt_fval = zeros(length(b))

%start optimization of list of targets (`b`s)
for idx = 1, length(b)
  objfun = @(x)objfun_builder(x,b)

  %optimization just like before

  opt_x(idx) = x
  opt_fval(idx) = fval
end
```

Comment: can you please see my update, I think I need more help, thank you.